# Using Enum in sec:authorize="hasRole(...)" (Spring Boot and Thymeleaf)

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I try to replace

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')"></div>
```

by

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole(${T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN.getText()})"></div>
```

but it does not work. Then I tried

```
<div th:with="role=${T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN.getText()}" sec:authorize="hasRole(${role})"></div>
```

and with preprocessing

```
<div th:with="role=${T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN.getText()}" sec:authorize="hasRole(__${role}__)"></div>
```

but is still not working.

Comment: Try `sec:authorize="hasRole(T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN)"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole(T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN)"></div>
```

Thanks @ChetanAhirrao

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<div th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''' + T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN.getText() + ''')')}">
  
</div>
```

(I don't think the `sec:` attributess interpret Thymeleaf expressions same as other tags... at least I couldn't find any examples of it.)

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but I want to keep `sec:authorize`.

Comment: For `th:if` you could also use `${#request.isUserInRole(T(com.mypackage.Role).ADMIN)}`